# Getting the controller action before behaviour code runs in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to execute some code inside a `Yii2` controller as I need some code from the model to be accessible within the `behaviors` section so I can pass the model as a parameter and avoid running duplicate queries; however I also need to be able to find out what `action` is being called, but I am not having much luck.

I have tried using `beforeAction` but it seems this gets run **AFTER** the `behaviours` code runs, so that doesn't help me.

I then tried using `init`, but it seems the `action` isn't available via `$this->action->id` at that point.

Some example code:

```
class MyController extends Controller { 

    public $defaultAction = 'view';

    public function init() {

        // $this->action not available in here

    }

    public function beforeAction() {

        // This is of no use as this runs *after* the 'behaviors' method

    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => NewAccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['view','example1','example2'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => false,
                        'authManager' => [
                            'model' => $this->model,
                            'other_param' => $foo,
                            'other_param' => $bar,
                        ],
                        'actions' => ['view'],
                    ],
                    // everything else is denied
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function viewAction() {

        // This is how it is currently instantiated, but we want to instantiate *before* the behavior code is run so we don't need to instantiate it twice
        // but to be able to do that we need to know the action so we can pass in the correct scenario

        $model = new exampleModel(['scenario' => 'view']);

    }

}
```

`authManager` is simply a reference to a `member variable` inside an extension of the `AccessRule` class.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: are you talking about *AccessControll* `matchCallback` or some custom behavior ?

Comment: @Tony Since I posted this question I have since changed how I am doing things, however I still need to be able to access code from the model within the `behaviors` section so I can pass the model as a parameter and avoid running duplicate queries. I will update my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if I get you right, you are looking for something like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $model = MyModel::find()->someQuery();
    $action = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
    return [
         'someBehavior' => [
             'class' => 'behavior/namespace/class',
             'callback' => function() use ($model, $action) {
                 //some logic here
             }
         ]
    ];
}
```

Because `behaviors()` is just a method, you can declare any variables and add any logic that you want in it, the only one convention that you must follow - is that return type must be an *array*.

If you use your custom behavior, you are able to use `events()` method where you can bind your behavior's methods to certain events. E.g.

```
class MyBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function events()
    {
        return [
            \yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN => 'myAfterLoginEvent',
        ];
    }

    public function myAfterLoginEvent($event)
    {
        //dealing with event
    }
}
```

In this example `myAfterLoginEvent` will be executed after user successfully  login into application. `$event` variable will be passed by framework and depending of event type it will contain different data. Read [about event object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-event.html)

**UPDATE:**

As I can see now my answer was more generic about events and behaviors. And now when you added code, I can suggest to you to override *behavior's* `beforeAction($action)` method with the following code:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    $actionID = $action->id;
    /* @var $rule AccessRule */
    foreach ($this->rules as &$rule) {
        $model = &$rule->authManager['model'];
        //now set model scenario maybe like this
        $model->scenario = $actionID;
    }
    //now call parent implementation 
    parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Also take a look at *AccessControl* [implementation of `beforeAction`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/AccessControl.php#L112) method, it invokes for each rule `allows` method with passing current action to it as a parameter. So if you have class that extends *AccessRule*, you can either override *allows($action, $user, $request)* method or `matchCustom($action)` method to set appropriate model scenario. Hope this will help.

One more alternative:

override controller's `runAction($id, $params = [])` method. Here $id is *actionID* - exactly what you need. Check id, set appropriate model scenario and call `parent::runAction($id, $params);`

Comment: Wanted to avoid having to instantiate the models within the `behavior` method simply because you wouldn't normally expect to initialize your models there and I'm trying to keep things as organised as possible. Basically my situation is, currently I am instantiating the models within all the `action` methods within the controller, all of which use a different scenario that is passed to the model. So because I need to instantiate the model outside of the action methods so the model can be passed as a param within the behaviour code I need to know the `action` so I can pass the correct scenario.

Comment: You can get the action with `Yii::$app->controller->action->id`

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that isn't available as yet within the `init` method.

Comment: so why `beforeAction($action)` didn't work for you ? It's still hard to understand. Can you provide some code with explanations ?

Comment: Hmmmmm..... would be nice to be able to set it all within the controller itself to make the code easier to follow - perhaps your first suggestion of instantiating it within the controllers `behavior` method would be better; but I guess these are the only options I have right now since Yii doesn't currently offer anything more straightforward haha.... thanks!

Comment: @Brett Updated the answer with one more alternative )

Comment: Hmmm I don't mind that option. However, wouldn't `runAction` run *after* the `behavior` code similar to how `beforeAction` does?

Comment: `beforeAction` is invoked by `runAction` so it should run _before_ any other action related code

Comment: That actually seems to work well and makes it available within the behavior code - awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. Now after updating all the code I am still getting a blank page, through debugging it seems the rendering is still being done, but it is not being output for whatever reason - any idea?

Comment: nvm...... fixed it. Forgot to use `return` in my call to `parent::runAction($id, $params)`.