# Setting globally available code in Yii2 for a single request

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using `Yii2` and I have a situation where I want to make some code globally available, but *only* for that request.

My use case is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143273/getting-the-controller-action-before-behaviour-code-runs-in-yii2) where I am doing some permission checks via a `matchCallback`.

I need to run a few different permission checks and if I can't do them all in the one place via the `matchCallback` (because I can't access all of the data I need it seems at that specific time) - then I am trying to avoid having to run the query again.

So, I was wondering if I could store data retrieved from the database such as a JSON encoded permission array within my `matchCallback` functionaltiy so I could then access that array within another action.

I know I could use `flash data`, but that seems like it is more meant for the `next` request. Is there anything available for just the current request or should I just use `flash data` anyway?

Comment: Could you not just cache the result of your queries, and retrieve them later? Caching seems to fulfil what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoeMiller Well, aren't most queries cached by default anyway? However, the time to run the query again still would be far longer than it would to retrieve the data from a global variable for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder what would be the best practice here too...
As for me I'd use Yii::$app->params array for that purpose. It does not look very good as it's called 'params' and supposed to be some custom parameters like 'adminEmail' etc. But it works nice: it is readable and writable from everywhere and if you set some of its keys or values dynamically it will long only for this particular request - just what you want. It's like:

```
Yii::$app->params['myKey'] = $myValue;
...
$myValue = Yii::$app->params['myKey'];
```

Comment: Hmm true. Definitely an idea to consider. I will leave this open for awhile and see if there is any "proper" of doing this, but it may come down to having to use this solution. Cheers!

Comment: Yes I would be happy to see a better choice too.